# Stop iteration on some failure

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm running collection with data from csv file with structure:

```
method,operation
GET,"/accounts"
GET,"/payments"
```

For each row in csv file I call the endpoint. I want to stop processing csv file when I obtain status other than 200. So I tried put to tests:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = (responseCode.code === 200)

if (responseCode.code !== 200) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null); // stop collection processing
}
```

But it does not stop processing second row in csv file. The result after running collection is:

[image]

How can I achieve stop processing other rows in csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Have been messing with Postman (Desktop) for last 4/5 hours, and it’s not possible to achieve this (stopping iteration conditionally). But think it’s achievable with [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman).

1. You can either use the `-bail` [options](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#command-line-options) when using the CLI, and throw an error on the specific iteration when you want it to be stopped.
2. Else [programmatically code](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#using-newman-as-a-nodejs-module) to proceed with next iteration(s) run only when you condition is valid.